# Get entry by week number using Django ORM?

Tags: django, orm

I tried something like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(year__week=1)
```

It doesn't work. For now, I calculate the first day and the last day of the week and then use `gte` and `lte`, but it's less than efficient given that SQL comes with a `Week` function.

Comment: I can be really all what you can learn is that "year" is a "DateField"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that django DateField doesn't have week attribute, as weel as date object from Python. They have both year and month and also day, but not week attribute. I guess you need to translate week to day range and file a ticket on django website ;-)

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but it's so boring. Ok for the ticket.

Comment: I can tell you what isnt: try writing a patch for django :-) This should be a lot of fun ;-)

Comment: Lol, yeah, as soon as I meet my deadlines I'll do it. Don't wait for me :-D

Comment: You seem to have a lot of time to spend on SO, so maybe you find a little to code something for django ;-)